# How to invoke AWS Lambda function in account B (this Lambda in VPC) from Lambda in account A (Lambda in VPC)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

What I did:

1. I created a VPC Peering connection between these accounts
2. Internet Gateways also attached to each VPC
3. Route Tables also configured (to allow traffic from both sides)

Case 1:

I successfully tested invoking Lambda function (in VPC B) from another Lambda function (in VPC A) when these 2 VPCs are in same account.

However, when I created a similar VPC (as VPC B) in another account (account B) I got the following error:

> "errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the Invoke operation: User: arn:aws:sts::Account-A:assumed-role/role-for-vpc-peering-test/lambda1_in_vpc is not authorized to perform: lambda:InvokeFunction on resource: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:Account-B:function:lambda-vpc

My trails:

I created a cross-account IAM Role for account A in account B with the following permissions:

[image: IAM Role]

Then I added an inline policy for the role which is using Lambda in account A:

[image: IAM Permissions]

Added policy to above role only:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::Account B:role/role-for-Account-A"
    }
}
```

So my questions is should I do anything else to invoke Lambda in account B from Lambda in account A?

I think I am missing something in the cross-account role only (`access denied error`).

lambda- A code:

import json
import boto3

client = boto3.client('lambda')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    inputForInvoker = {'CustomerId': '123', 'Amount': 50 }

```
response = client.invoke(
    FunctionName='arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:AccountB-id:function:lambda-vpc-peering',
    InvocationType='RequestResponse', # Event
    Payload=json.dumps(inputForInvoker)
    )

responseJson = json.load(response['Payload'])

print('\n')
print(responseJson)
print('\n')
```

Any suggestions?

Assume role- in Account b is : have following Policies : 1. AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole 
2.trust-policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::Account-id-A:role/role-for-vpc-peering-test"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}.
```

execution role - attached  this inline policy :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::Account-b-id:role/role-for-7691-4701-2358"
    }
}
```

and updated my lambda function with  below mention code also.

but still getting same error

now lambdas are not in vpc.

Comment: What's your lambda code in A? You have to assume the role in B, using, e.g. `sts.assume_role(...)` boto3 call.

Comment: yaa i created  cross accout role in account b only to use in account A

Comment: I will and answer, as I don't want to paste code in comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General steps required for **assuming a role in Account A** to do something in Account B (e.g. invoke lambda function in B) are listed in the following AWS blog:

- [How can I configure a Lambda function to assume a role from another AWS account?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-assume-iam-role/)

The important thing to note is that the lambda function in Account A has to **assume role** in Account B. The assumable role must allow execution role of function A to invoke function in B.

I modified your code for lambda in Account A, based on the example from the above link.

The **key elements to focus are**:

- sts = boto3.client('sts')
- account_b = sts.assume_role(...)
- account_b_client = boto3.client(...)

Assuming that all your roles are correctly set, your code should look something like blow. Obviously you have to adjust it exactly to your needs, but it should give you **general idea of what to do** in your lambda in Account A.

```
import json 
import boto3 

client = boto3.client('lambda') 

sts = boto3.client('sts')

def lambda_handler(event, context): 

    inputForInvoker = {'CustomerId': '123', 'Amount': 50 } 

    account_b = sts.assume_role(
        RoleArn="<arn-of-assumbale-role-in-acccount-b>",
        RoleSessionName="cross_acct_lambda"
    )

    ACCESS_KEY = account_b['Credentials']['AccessKeyId']
    SECRET_KEY = account_b['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey']
    SESSION_TOKEN = account_b['Credentials']['SessionToken']

    # create service client using the assumed role credentials
    # from account B
    account_b_client = boto3.client(
        'lambda',
        aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
        aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
        aws_session_token=SESSION_TOKEN)

    response = account_b_client.invoke(FunctionName='arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:AccountB-id:function:lambda-vpc-peering', InvocationType='RequestResponse') 

    responseJson = json.load(response['Payload']) 
    print('\n') print(responseJson) print('\n')
```

p.s.

> 1. I created a VPC Peering connection between these accounts

This is **not needed.** Invocation of function B from function A will go over internet anyway. So if you don't use the peering connection for anything other, that its not used for the lambdas.

Comment: hey Marcin could u look at this  still i am facing same access denied error ( i mentioned updated stuff at end )

Comment: @MaldannaGk Probably roles are incorrect. Can you add to your question the names of the: Execution role for function in Acc A, execution role for function in Acc B, and cross-account role in B to be assumed by lambda in Acc A?